# Read files simultaneously using nodejs fs

Tags: node.js, fs, readfile, async.js

I wanted to know what is the most efficient method for reading multiple files at the same time.
i have an array of files paths and I want to create an array of data using fs read file (not asyncRead and not using call back function) arranged according to the index of the array of paths.
i need to read three files simultaneously, And I can not find how to simultaneously read files.

I found this method but can't figure out if it reads the files at the same time and if so how:

```
***function simultaneouslyRead(filePath1, filePath2){
    var async = require('async'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    files = [filePath1, filePath2];
    async.map(files, fs.readFile, function(err, files) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        files.forEach(function(file) {
          console.log(file.toString());
      });
    });
  }***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create a promise based version of [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), then use Promise.all to read all the files into an array, something like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const promiseReadFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

async function readFiles(files) {
    const fileArray = await Promise.all(files.map(file => promiseReadFile(file)));
    console.log("File contents:", fileArray);
    return fileArray;
}

readFiles(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']);
```

The fileArray will contain an array of Buffers once the data has been read.

A revised version, incorporating errors from any read failures:

```
const fs = require("fs");

function promiseReadFile(path, options = {}) {
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        fs.readFile(path, options, (err, data) => resolve({ err, data }));
    });
}

async function readFiles(files) {
    const fileArray = await Promise.all(files.map(file => promiseReadFile(file)));
    console.log("File contents:", fileArray);
    return fileArray;
}

readFiles(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']);
```

Comment: Your solutions is OK,but if he decides to write back file1 and file2 would probably not be exactly the same,right?

Comment: We're reading each file to a buffer as the file is at that time, effectively snapshotting the contents. Of course the files could change before or after. If one wanted to lock the files one could pursue that route, though I believe this is outside of the scope of the question at the moment.

Comment: your solution is great but what if there will be an err in one file( not found, cloudnt open etc) , i want the end result to be the contents of the opened files and the errors of the unopened files, how to catch the errors in reading at the same time?

Comment: That's a good point. In the first version, if we encounter any errors we'll get a Promise reject on the Promise.all call. We can create a custom promiseReadFile function that will attempt to read all files and save any errors resulting from this. In this case we'll get an array of results : [{ data: {}, err: {}, ... etc]

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs= require('fs').promises;

async function readFiles(files) {
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(files.map(file=> fs.readFile(file)));
    console.log(results);
    return results;
}

readFiles(['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']);
```